# How do I enable CD-in?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a TV card that is connected to the CD-in (JCD1) connector on my mother board.

However, I could not find a setting in `pavucontrol` to playback the sound from that port in Ubuntu. Am I just missing something or do I need to install additional software?

The CD port also does not show up in `alsamixer`. I found a fix for Realtek ALC1200 codec [here](http://www.spinics.net/linux/fedora/alsa-user/msg11769.html) but it didn't work for me (my board is using Realtek ALC888).

Comment: Please add additional information to the question, rather than adding it in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the CD slider to show up in `alsamixer`. This is based on the description found at http://www.spinics.net/linux/fedora/alsa-user/msg11769.html

First, create a file `/lib/firmware/hda-init.fw` with the following contents:

```
[codec]
0x10ec0888 0x14627522 0

[pincfg]
0x1c 0x993301f0
```

These are the values for my mainboard. I am assuming that they are identical for yours if you are also using the Realtek ALC888 codec. You can find these value by using the [`alsa-info.sh` script](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo). Your output should contain something like this:

```
!!HDA-Intel Codec information
!!---------------------------
--startcollapse--

Codec: Realtek ALC888
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0888
Subsystem Id: 0x14627522
```

The numbers from Vendor Id and Subsystem Id are the ones that need to go in the file we created above under the `[codec]` line.

I have no idea what the `[pincfg]` line actually does and what those numbers are but it seems to work.

Once you have created that file we need to tell ALSA to read it. Open `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and add the following line at the end of the file:

```
options snd-hda-intel patch=hda-init.fw
```

Now the CD slider should show up after reloading ALSA. However, this did not work for me. Restarting my machine, however, did fix it.

Now you can just use the ALSA mixer to crank up the CD volume and you should hear the sound on your speakers.

Note that at least on my machine the CD slider seems to be muted by default. You will be able to set the CD volume but you will not hear anything unless you unmute it. To do that press `M` and you should hear the sound.