# How do I redirect input from one sound card to output on another sound card?

Tags: sound, 14.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a TV card with its sound output connected to the CD-in of my mainboard's built-in sound card. There is also a USB sound device connected to my machine. Now I want to play the sound from the TV card via the USB sound output.

I tried the solutions proposed in [How do I output my audio input?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2719/how-do-i-output-my-audio-input) but they don't work for me. When I run those commands all I get is a lot of low frequency feedback that quickly adds up so that I need to terminate the command after a few seconds.

The reasons for this seems to be that the input source selected in `pavucontrol` for my internal sound card is my microphone. However, the CD input does not show up in `pavucontrol`, it only shows up in `alsamixer`.

Is there something that I am missing here? How can I play my CD-in from my internal sound card via my USB sound device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some fiddling, I managed to get my CD input recognized by ALSA, see [my answer on the other question](https://askubuntu.com/a/382125/14220). Now it shows up in `alsamixer`.

I ended up using the solution provided in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/412616/14220). I created a script in my home directory which contains the following code:

`pacat -r --device=alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo | pacat -p --latency-msec=1`

While this is running, sound input from the input device selected in `alsamixer` (press F4 to switch to input controls) is redirected to my USB audio device. Unfortunately, the input device is reset whenever I lock my screen so I have to change it back to my CD-in repeatedly. If anyone knows how to circumvent this, please let me know.